# Using props to control modal

Tags: react-native

In one of my screen, I have a modal to show some option.
Here is my modal in WelcomeScreen.js:

```
this.state={
   showLoginOption:false
   }

...

 <Modal visible={this.state.showLoginOption} animationType='slide'>
<Icon name='ios-close' onPress={()=>this.setState({showMe:false})} >
<Modal/>

 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({showLoginOption:true})} />
```

It works totally fine, but in order to improve the readability of my code, I want to turn it into a component file. However, I don't really know how to control the visible property via props.

I have tried this in my new component:

WelcomeScreen.js

```
this.state={
  showLoginOption:false
  }

...

<LoginOption showMe={this.state.showLoginOption}/>

...
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({showLoginOption:true})} />
```

LoginOption.js

```
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state={
           showMe:props.showMe
       }
   }
...
<Modal visible={this.state.showMe} animationType='slide'>
<Icon name='ios-close' onPress={()=>this.setState({showMe:false})} >
<Modal/>
```

This time when I press TouchableOpacity, nothing happened.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//WelcomeScreen.js
this.state={
  showLoginOption:false
  }

 //function for handle modal visibility 
 handleModalVisibility : (action)=> this.setState({showLoginOption : action})

...

<LoginOption showMe={this.state.showLoginOption} modalVisibility={this.handleModalVisibility}/>

...
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleModalVisibility.bind(this,true)} />
```

```
 export const LoginOption  = ({showMe,modalVisibility})=> (
 <Modal visible={showMe} animationType='slide'>
 <Icon name='ios-close' onPress={modalVisibility.bind(this,false)} >
 <Modal/>
)
```

Comment: hi daniel6a1015 did you get it what is trying above code?

Comment: i am just binding the param to true/false it will pass whenever onPress triggere...

Comment: assume this is just shortcut for onPress= {()=>this.modalVisibility(true)}

Comment: did u get it daniel?

Comment: It works! Thank you. Can you explain why my code is not working?

Comment: you need to understand how props and state behave... that is the mistake you did